# My app to show on both iphone and ipad in app store without having me to filter it by "iphone only"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, xcode5

I am working on an app which does not show up in the app store until I switch to iPhone only. The app was built with targeted device family: iphone/ipad and runs properly on both the devices. But when using ipad, I have to search the app "iphone only" in app store. Thanks!!

My question is :

1)  Is there any way I can set it up so that it shows on both iphone and ipad in app store without having me to filter it by "iphone only"?

Comment: Did you specify that the app is `universal` in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in xcode you select **Universal**, Apple will automatically parse your app so that it works on iPad and iPhone. If you only want it to work on iPad select iPad and iPhone for iPhone.

[image: Device Selection]

You can change this from Project Name->General

---

Also if I'm not mistaken you don't provide screenshots for one of the devices during your App registration on itunesconnect, that device won't be available until you have screenshots for it.